# Django update index after adding records to db programmatically

Tags: django

I added a number of records to a Django db table (machina forums) directly via a script (ie: I did not use the site admin interface). The structure seemed fairly straightforward with no foreign keys in other tables.

However the resulting displays are uneven. In a forum index display all of the children forums display under a category. However if I go into the category, only forums added via the admin interface are visible. There does not appear to be any difference in the db records between those that were added programmatically and those added via the admin interface.

I am guessing the issue has to do with indexes on the table. However when I use a GUI to view the db all of the indexes show "result set is empty."

Any ideas about what is causing the problem and if it is index related, how do I update the index?

Here is the view that creates the forum displays:

```
Forum views
    ===========
    This module defines views provided by the ``forum`` application.
"""

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView

from machina.apps.forum.signals import forum_viewed
from machina.conf import settings as machina_settings
from machina.core.db.models import get_model
from machina.core.loading import get_class


Forum = get_model('forum', 'Forum')
Topic = get_model('forum_conversation', 'Topic')

ForumVisibilityContentTree = get_class('forum.visibility', 'ForumVisibilityContentTree')
PermissionRequiredMixin = get_class('forum_permission.viewmixins', 'PermissionRequiredMixin')
TrackingHandler = get_class('forum_tracking.handler', 'TrackingHandler')


class IndexView(ListView):
    """ Displays the top-level forums. """

    context_object_name = 'forums'
    template_name = 'forum/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """ Returns the list of items for this view. """
        return ForumVisibilityContentTree.from_forums(
            self.request.forum_permission_handler.forum_list_filter(
                Forum.objects.all(), self.request.user,
            ),
        )

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """ Returns the context data to provide to the template. """
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        visiblity_content_tree = context['forums']

        # Computes some global values.
        context['total_posts_count'] = sum(n.posts_count for n in visiblity_content_tree.top_nodes)
        context['total_topics_count'] = sum(
            n.topics_count for n in visiblity_content_tree.top_nodes
        )

        return context


class ForumView(PermissionRequiredMixin, ListView):
    """ Displays a forum and its topics. If applicable, its sub-forums can also be displayed. """

    context_object_name = 'topics'
    paginate_by = machina_settings.FORUM_TOPICS_NUMBER_PER_PAGE
    permission_required = ['can_read_forum', ]
    template_name = 'forum/forum_detail.html'
    view_signal = forum_viewed

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        """ Handles GET requests. """
        forum = self.get_forum()
        if forum.is_link:
            response = HttpResponseRedirect(forum.link)
        else:
            response = super(ForumView, self).get(request, **kwargs)
        self.send_signal(request, response, forum)
        return response

    def get_forum(self):
        """ Returns the forum to consider. """
        if not hasattr(self, 'forum'):
            self.forum = get_object_or_404(Forum, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return self.forum

    def get_queryset(self):
        """ Returns the list of items for this view. """
        self.forum = self.get_forum()
        qs = (
            self.forum.topics
            .exclude(type=Topic.TOPIC_ANNOUNCE)
            .exclude(approved=False)
            .select_related('poster', 'last_post', 'last_post__poster')
        )
        return qs

    def get_controlled_object(self):
        """ Returns the controlled object. """
        return self.get_forum()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """ Returns the context data to provide to the template. """
        context = super(ForumView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Insert the considered forum into the context
        context['forum'] = self.get_forum()

        # Get the list of forums that have the current forum as parent
        context['sub_forums'] = ForumVisibilityContentTree.from_forums(
            self.request.forum_permission_handler.forum_list_filter(
                context['forum'].get_descendants(), self.request.user,
            ),
        )

        # The announces will be displayed on each page of the forum
        context['announces'] = list(
            self.get_forum()
            .topics.select_related('poster', 'last_post', 'last_post__poster')
            .filter(type=Topic.TOPIC_ANNOUNCE)
        )

        # Determines the topics that have not been read by the current user
        context['unread_topics'] = TrackingHandler(self.request).get_unread_topics(
            list(context[self.context_object_name]) + context['announces'], self.request.user,
        )

        return context

    def send_signal(self, request, response, forum):
        """ Sends the signal associated with the view. """
        self.view_signal.send(
            sender=self, forum=forum, user=request.user, request=request, response=response,
        )
```

Comment: Can you share the view that is not displaying what you want? The DB will handle the table indexes, you don't need to do anything. Is the issue to do with permissions?

Comment: I added the forum views above. I thought it could be a permissions issue, but it also occurs with the admin user.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're talking about some custom solution and it is hard to help without additional details like SQL queries that you've applied, model code,  queries, and their returns.

Comment: I didn't make any changes to the Django-Machina code base. I only added the forums programmatically instead of adding via the admin interface.